Is there a way to add DeliveryOptions using IMessageBus.InvokeAsync?
I want to send a message of type TMessage and wait for a TResult through the IMessageBus. I want to include some DeliveryOptions like Headers and TenantId.
However, the IMessageBus.InvokeAsync<TResult> method does not allows for this. I can use InvokeForTenantAsync to include the tenant, but no headers are allowed in any overload.
I would not want to re-implement InvokeAsync based on SendAsync (which allows including headers), and the source code is hard to follow due to the indirection in this line, so there is no sample implementation at hand.
I could use a middleware for this but there should be a way to do this on site, isn't it?
